# C append chars into char array one by one

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have made up a function which returns some chars , all I want to do is to append all those returned chars into one string .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char func(int n);
int main()
{
    int i;
    char str[] = "";
    size_t p = strlen(str);

    for (i =0 ; i < 5; i++){
        str[p++] = func(i);
        str[p] = '\0';
        p++;
    }

    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}


char func(int n){
    if (n == 0)
      return '1';
    if (n == 1)
      return '2';
    if (n > 1)
      return '3';

}
```

//EDIT Output for this is `19`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `char str[] = "";` creates an array with size = 1 byte. Allocate more space: `char str[256];` or some value. Then you'll want to initialize `size_t p = 0;` And, you increment `p` 2x in the loop.  Get rid of one.

Comment: You are overwriting the stack because `str` is not big enough to store all the characters.

Comment: you need to create some space for `str`. From what you have above, `str` needs at least 6 bytes to fit all the data: `char str[6] = "";`

Comment: What if I do not know how much of space I am going to need?

Comment: go big or go home

Comment: @P.Bolfa Use functions like `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`.

Comment: _"Input for this is"_ ...OK? And the output is? And that was wrong because? This is a very unclear question. Also, it doesn't look like you've done much basic research on how C deals with strings; it's expected that you would do so before posting.

Comment: @P.Bolfa Take a look at the [get_string()](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c) method in Harvard's cs50.c library. In particular, look at how it uses realloc() to [double the size of the input buffer](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c#L170) whenever the buffer fills up.

Answer (score 2):

```c
char func(n){
    if (n == 0)
      return '1';
    if (n == 1)
      return '2';
    if (n > 1)
      return '3';
}
```

You should always specify the type for variables.

Please use something like `int n` instead of just `n`.

It's also bad that all of your returns are conditional, it's better to have a return statement that's guaranteed to be executed no matter what *:

```c
char func(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return '1';
    if (n == 1) return '2';

    return '3';
}
```

** Because not returning a value from a function that **should** return a value is undefined behaviour.*

Now that we have that out of the way, let's have a look at your `main()`:

```c
int main() {
    int i;
    char str[] = "";
    size_t p = strlen(str);

    for (i =0 ; i < 5; i++){
        str[p++] = func(i);
        str[p] = '\0';
        p++;
    }

    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

- `str[]` is not big enough to store all the characters you write to it, resulting in undefined behaviour.
- Your loop body is written in a weird way, why are you incrementing `p` twice?

Here a very simple program that writes 5 characters into `str`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char func(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return '1';
    if (n == 1) return '2';

    return '3';
}

int main() {
    int i;
    // Allocate 6 bytes (5 characters) on the stack
    char str[6] = "";

    for (i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
        str[i] = func(i);
    }

    // Strings *must* be NULL terminated in C
    str[5] = 0;

    printf("%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Strings *must* be NULL terminated in C" and that one already is. Anyway, good one.

Answer (score 0):

The size of your str here is "0" (0 using the strlen and 1 using the sizeof operator because it counts the '\0' caracter) so you can not add more element to the str, and if you try, the program will crash. So you have two possibilies here, the first is to declare a fixed table size and the number n will be limited by the size, the second is a dynamic one using mallic. To intialize it to zeros you can just use the memset API.

Answer (score 0):

Well short answer is everything you did would be right if you have in the array enough memory to hold those `5` characters and the `\0` if you want to treat it as a string (NUL terminated `char` array).

`""` is a string literal containing only the `\0`. Length of this string is `0`. What about the array? Applying `sizeof` over it reveals that it is capable of holding one character. (Well it contained `\0`).

Now with your code you surely did access positions that are beyond the size of the array. This is undefined behavior - mentioned by the C standard.

Solution is to either have an array having size capable of holding the maximum character you would like to store someday. Or you can have a `char*` to which you can assign address of allocated chunk by using functions like `malloc`,`realloc` etc. Benefit of this, you can increase memory as much as you need on runtime depending on the number of characters you want to store.